# Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (using gorm and mysql)

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

when I add gorm model to my struct i got this error

im using gorm model in my other 3 struct but only when i add this to my journal struct i got error  Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
here are my structs

```
package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Category struct {
   gorm.Model
   Title string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
   Sort  int    `gorm:"sort"`
}
```

package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Contents struct {
gorm.Model
CategoryId    uint
CategoryModel Category `gorm:"foreignKey:category_id"`
Title         string   `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
Content       string   `gorm:"content"`
Status        bool     `gorm:"default:true"`
Sort          int      `gorm:"sort"`
Images        []Image  `gorm:"foreignKey:content_id"`
}

```
package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Image struct {
   gorm.Model
   ContentId    uint
   ContentModel Contents `gorm:"foreignKey:content_id"`
   Title        string   `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
   File         string
   Sort         int `gorm:"sort"`
}

//`gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
```

```
package migrations

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Journal struct {
   gorm.Model
   ModelName string `gorm:"ModelName"`
   UpdatedBy string `gorm:"UpdatedBy"`
   Row       uint   `gorm:"foreignKey:category_id"`
   NewValue  string `gorm:"newValue"`
   OldValue  string `gorm:"oldValue"`
   Column    string `gorm:"Column"`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When gorm do migration it usually migrates what is added to table. But if you remove any thing from struct that thing is not removed from table while migration. Suppose there was a `Key` column of `auto` type. If you remove it from struct it will not be auto removed from table after migration rather you need to manually remove it from table. I think this type of scenario happened with you.